# Difference between glBitmap and glTexImage2D

Tags: opengl

I need to display image in openGL window.
Image changes every timer tick.
I've checked on google how, and as I can see it can be done using or *glBitmap* or *glTexImage2D* functions.
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference? These two functions have nothing in common.

[`glBitmap`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBitmap.xml) is a function for drawing *binary images*. That's not a .BMP file or an image you load (usually). The function's name doesn't refer to the colloquial term "bitmap". It refers to exact that: a map of bits. Each bit in the bitmap represents a *pixel*. If the bit is 1, then the current raster color will be written to the framebuffer. If the bit is 0, then the pixel in the framebuffer will not be altered.

[`glTexImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexImage2D) is for allocating [textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture) and optionally [uploading pixel data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) to them. You can later draw triangles that have that texture mapped to them. But `glTexImage2D` by itself does not draw anything.

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is [glDrawPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml), which draws an image directly into the framebuffer. If you use `glTexImage2D`, you have to first update the texture with the new image, then draw a shape with that texture (say, a fullscreen quad) to actually render the image.

That said, you'll be better off with `glTexImage2D` if...

- You're using a library like JOGL that makes binding textures from images an easy operation, or
- You want to scale the image or display it in perspective

Comment: Or if you like performance. `glDrawPixels` is very slow. Also, if you want to do any form of manipulation on those pixels (tinting them, maybe rotating it, etc). Basically... never use `glDrawPixels`. There's a reason the ARB tossed it out with GL 3.1.

Comment: Good point. I considered adding a note to the effect of, "Since textures do everything you could want, why learn an obscure special-purpose API just for this?" (I do think, however, that since the image is changing every frame, drawing it with `glDrawPixels` is no slower than copying it to a texture every frame)